# Pytz - timezone activated yet getting wrong time. Am I missing something?

Tags: django, python-2.7, timezone, pytz

On my main page I get the following view definition triggered

```
def initializeTimeZone(request):
    tzone = request.GET.get("tzone") # returns 'America/Los_Angeles'
    user_time_zone = request.session.get('user_time_zone', None)
    try:
        if user_time_zone is None:
            request.session['user_time_zone'] = tzone
            timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(tzone)) #--->is this correct ? 
            time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime(settings.DATE_TIME_OBJECT_FORMATTING) #--->Wrong
        return HttpResponse("OK")
    except Exception as ex:
        print >> sys.stderr, str(ex)
```

Now when I do something like this later on

```
time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime(settings.DATE_TIME_OBJECT_FORMATTING)
```

I get the wrong date
'2017-07-09 19:01:33'

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: where are you accessing the time? is it within the same users request or just somewhere else in code? or a template?

Comment: I am accessing the time at a different part . I introduced the time part right after activating the timezone (updated my post) to make sure its still wrong and it still is.

Comment: if it was working properly would it be used in a template or some other user request?

Comment: if it was working properly it would be used inside a view definition making an entry into the database.Unfortunately the time here is 12:20 pm and it says that its 7pm

Comment: Seems like the utc time generated is correct though

Comment: database entries are supposed to be stored as UTC to allow you to handle multiple timezones or daylight savings time. (just trying to understand the bigger picture to help you). Once they are in the database how will you access them? I am not sure whats going on with the timezone activate but I am not sure that you are using the right method to get what you want

Comment: Yeh I read more on this. Seems like I need to write to my db in UTC time and then convert to local timezone when displaying ? Is that correct ? By default pytz does UTC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148738/discussion-between-william-reed-and-mistyd).

Answer (score 2):

Here is my general approach to make sure timezones and datetimes are stored and displayed properly.

First make sure that `USE_TZ = True` in your `settings.py` file and make sure `TIME_ZONE='UTC'` there as well.

So when adding datetimes to a database make sure they are in UTC to avoid problems with multiple timezones or daylight savings.

I normally set a session timezone using middleware as per the example at the bottom of this post. I only change it to no longer use the deprecated MiddlewareMixin (so you would need django 1.10+ to follow this, otherwise look more below)

```
import pytz

from django.utils import timezone

# make sure you add `TimezoneMiddleware` appropriately in settings.py
class TimezoneMiddleware(object):
    """
    Middleware to properly handle the users timezone
    """

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # make sure they are authenticated so we know we have their tz info.
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            # we are getting the users timezone string that in this case is stored in 
            # a user's profile
            tz_str = request.user.profile.timezone
            timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(tz_str))
        # otherwise deactivate and the default time zone will be used anyway
        else:
            timezone.deactivate()

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

After adjusting that to properly use the users timezone, make sure you add it to middleware in `settings.py`

Now, when datetime objects are accessed in templates they will automatically be converted from the 'UTC' format of the database to whatever time zone the user is in. Just access the datetime object and its timezone will be set assuming the previous middleware is set up properly.

```
{{ my_datetime_value }}
```

If you desire a fine grained control of whether the user's timezone is used take a look at the following:

```
{% load tz %}
{% localtime on %}
    {# this time will be respect the users time zone #}
    {{ your_date_time }}
{% endlocaltime %}

{% localtime off %}
    {# this will not respect the users time zone #}
    {{ your_date_time }}
{% endlocaltime %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/timezones/

---

---

**Enable Time Zone Support**

First is first, ensure that `USE_TZ = True` in your `settings.py` file. Also set a default time zone value to `TIME_ZONE` such as `TIME_ZONE='UTC'`. View a complete list of timezones [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

If `USE_TZ` is False, `TIME_ZONE` will be the time zone that Django will use to store all datetimes. When `USE_TZ` is enabled,  `TIME_ZONE` is the default time zone that Django will use to display datetimes in templates and to interpret datetimes entered in forms.

With time zone support enabled, django will store `datetime` data in the database as the time zone `UTC`

---

---

**Setting Session Timezones**

Python's `datetime.datetime` objects have a `tzinfo` attribute that is used to store time zone information. When the attribute is set the object is considered Aware, when the attribute is not set it is considered a Naive.

To ensure that a timezone is naive or aware, you can use [`.is_naive()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.is_naive) and [`.is_aware()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.is_aware)

If you have `USE_TZ` enabled in your `settings.py` file, a `datetime` will have time zone information attached to it as long as your default `TIME_ZONE` is set in `settings.py`

While this default time zone may be good in some cases it is likely not enough especially if you are handling users in multiple time zones. In order to accomplish this, middleware must be used.

```
import pytz

from django.utils import timezone

# make sure you add `TimezoneMiddleware` appropriately in settings.py
class TimezoneMiddleware(object):
    """
    Middleware to properly handle the users timezone
    """

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # make sure they are authenticated so we know we have their tz info.
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            # we are getting the users timezone that in this case is stored in 
            # a user's profile
            tz_str = request.user.profile.timezone
            timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(tz_str))
        # otherwise deactivate and the default time zone will be used anyway
        else:
            timezone.deactivate()

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

There are a few new things going on. In `__call__` we are handling the setting of the timezone data. At first we make sure the user is authenticated, to make sure that we have timezone data for this user. Once we know we do, we active the timezone for the users session using `timezone.activate()`. In order to convert the time zone string we have to something usable by datetime, we use `pytz.timezone(str)`.

Now, when datetime objects are accessed in templates they will automatically be converted from the 'UTC' format of the database to whatever time zone the user is in. Just access the datetime object and its timezone will be set assuming the previous middleware is set up properly.

```
{{ my_datetime_value }}
```

If you desire a fine grained control of whether the user's timezone is used take a look at the following:

```
{% load tz %}
{% localtime on %}
    {# this time will be respect the users time zone #}
    {{ your_date_time }}
{% endlocaltime %}

{% localtime off %}
    {# this will not respect the users time zone #}
    {{ your_date_time }}
{% endlocaltime %}
```

*Note, this method described only works in Django 1.10 and on. To support django from prior to 1.10 look into [MiddlewareMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware)*

Comment: I total understand the utility of automatically handling timezones when dealing with what's displayed to the user. But why is the heck does `timezone.activate` also affect how `time` objects timezones are treated in DB queries?! That is not user facing and causes unreliable results from DB queries that filter on time.